# Object doesn't support property or method 'push'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a hidden field on my webpage which I want to store a collection of objects. The html for this is:

```
<div><input type="hidden" id="CheckedSubGroups" value="[]" /></div>
```

I then have the following jQuery:

```
 $(".SubGroupCheckBoxes").on("click", function() {
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                var array = $("#CheckedSubGroups").val();
                array.push('test object');
                $("#CheckedSubGroups").val(array);
            } else
                // do other stuff
```

This blows up however with a "this Object doesn't support the push property or method" error

In the debugger I've stopped at this line and checked the value of the array object which is given as "[]"

Comment: The value returned is a string, hence you can't push to it. It may be better to create an actual array, push to that and store it in a `data` attribute of the `form`, but that will depend on how you wish to access the information later on.

Comment: A string containing the characters `[]` is not the same thing as an array.

Comment: var array is not an array its return string

Comment: did you try to handle it with JSON? like ... `array = JSON.parse(...val());` `....val(JSON.stringify(array);`

Comment: Post your (relevant) HTML as well. Use `change` event on checkboxes.

Comment: .val method return string on input element, it return array  only on select element with multiple section enabled.
http://api.jquery.com/val/
save the value in comma saperated fashion and array.split(','), will give  the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you try to handle it with JSON? like ...
 `var array = JSON.parse($("#CheckedSubGroups").val());`
 `$("#CheckedSubGroups").val(JSON.stringify(array);`

```
$(".SubGroupCheckBoxes").on("click", function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        var array = JSON.parse($("#CheckedSubGroups").val());
        array.push('test object');
        $("#CheckedSubGroups").val(JSON.stringify(array));
    } else
        // do other stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `$("#CheckedSubGroups").val()` may return a string instead of an array.

So you should convert this string to array before invoking `push` method

```
var array = JSON.parse($("#CheckedSubGroups").val());
```

Comment: will cause an error when the function will called 2nd time, because the val is not valid json. strinigy before set to val

Answer (score 0):

You don't direct push value into array. You have to need an array object. Your variable's value need to convert into array object.

> The push() method adds new items to the end of an array, and returns
>   the new length.

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.push("Kiwi");
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp